# Will MOC created as child of an other MOC include unsaved changes too?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I create `temporaryContext` like below. Will it include unsaved changes or only saved ones from `Utility.managedObjectContext()`?

```
let temporaryContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
temporaryContext.parentContext = Utility.managedObjectContext()
temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({
```

I haven't found anything about it in Core Data Programming Tutorial.

Comment: better u can try in this link : https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is NO.

The child will only have items that were persisted *before the child fetched them*.

This is different than before the child was created.